# Weak and Probability convergences

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, random-matrices

I have a question about this book, "Topics in Random Matrices Theory" of Terence Tao.

[image: page 160]

He claims that if 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi \ d\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n}\stackrel{P}\rightarrow\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi \ d\mu\hspace{2cm}(1)$$
for every $\varphi\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$, i.e, for every function $\varphi$ continuous and bounded, then 
$$\hspace{1cm}\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n}\stackrel{P}\rightarrow\mu\hspace{3.4cm}(2)$$

This looks natural, and in fact, he doesn't even prove this, looks like it is an obvious result. First I thought it would follow directly from the definition of weak convergence, but the convergence in (1) is weaker then weak convergence, and I could'n find any result about this implication. I hope someone help me on this?

New Add: Here is another related text talking about the same thing. Maybe someone could read this and explain to me what is really going on.

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: How is $(1)$ weaker than weak convergence?

Comment: Given $\varepsilon >0$, if the convergence is weak, I can get $n$ big enough such that $$|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi \ d\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n} - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi \ d\mu| <\varepsilon$$
But for convergence in probability, I can get only $n$ big enough such that $$P\Big(|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi \ d\mu_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}M_n} - \int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi \ d\mu| <\varepsilon \Big)$$
is little, but yet, there is a chance to don't satisfy this for some entry.

Comment: Maybe im doing something, I dont discard this. In fact, probably Im doing something wrong and I want to understand this.

Comment: This seems excessive but can you use the fact that $C_c(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ (the space of continuous functions with compact support) is separable?  So there is a countable dense basis of functions $\mathcal{B}$. Therefore for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t for all $n>N$, $$\mathbb{P}\left( \sup_{\phi \in \mathcal{B}} \left | \int \phi d\mu_n  -  \int \phi d \mu \right| > \epsilon \right) < \epsilon.$$ Since this set is dense and $\mu_n$, $\mu$ are probability measure you can then propagate that supremum to the whole set which should give you what you want.

Comment: It seems to me that Tao didn't give an explanation of why this was considered a 'specialization' of the definitions of convergence he gave in the opening chapter of his book. There he talks about different types of convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ but there of course there is an underlying topology/metric. He doesn't seem to give a topology on the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. In general I believe one usually considers the vague topology - convergence of integrals for every continuous function of compact support.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't the expression in $(2)$ mean precisely what you quote Tao saying it means, which is that the limit in $(1)$ holds for all continuous $\phi$ with compact support? So wouldn't it obviously follow that if $(1)$ holds for all continuous and bounded $\phi$, then it holds for all continuous $\phi$ with compact support, and hence $(2)$ holds? Any notion of "weak converence" does not seem to enter here.

Comment: @Integral, just wondering, did you read my comment above?

Comment: @Will Nelson Im going to read every comment in a few hours.

Comment: @Integral: I think Ben has an important point. Tao talks about weak convergence on the metric space $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathbb{R})$ of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. We cannot possibly say much about the properties of such convergence unless we know what metric he considers on $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathbb{R})$, since weak convergence to a large degree is determined by this metric. Can you check your reference and find the metric?